# How to nest CTE properly

Tags: sql-server

This question was asked few other times, but I still did not manage to sort out the right answer or proper way to do this:

...

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT * FROM ...
)
SELECT *, [dbo].[udf_BetaInv](A, B, C, D) AS 'Loss'
FROM CTE
WHERE (Loss >= @MinRetention)
```

This does not work and I cannot create the stored procedure, clearly I cannot use Loss in the WHERE because does not exist in that scope.

I would like to use another CTE to wrap this one so I can put the WHERE on the outer one but not does not seem to work, tried this:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT * FROM ...
)
SELECT *, [dbo].[udf_BetaInv(A, B, C, D) AS 'Loss'
FROM CTE,
RESULTS AS
(SELECT * FROM CTE)
  SELECT *
  FROM RESULTS
  WHERE (Loss >= @MinRetention)
```

But it does not compile in SQL Server, I get an error that a '(' is misplaces many rows above but has nothing to do, if I remove the second CTE it works fine.

I only want to avoid code duplication, not want to call my [udf_BetaInv] twice in the select and also in the where.

Comment: Do you mean `[Loss]` (a column name) not `'Loss'` (a string)? Not sure if that'd cause the error, though

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have an intermediate `SELECT` that you should not have. This should work:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT * FROM ...
),
RESULTS AS
(
  SELECT *, [dbo].[udf_BetaInv(A, B, C, D) AS 'Loss'
  FROM CTE
)
SELECT *
FROM RESULTS
WHERE (Loss >= @MinRetention)
```

Comment: Thanks, work great as well, didn't realize I was having too many SELECTs :D

Comment: It's not necessary but a good pratice to explicitly name the columns in your CTE name, i.e. .... RESULTS([column names from CTE], loss) .... You will thank yourself later :P.

Answer (score 7):

Obviously the problem with the first query is that 'Loss' is just a column alias and can't be used in a `WHERE` clause. You're right that using it in a CTE would avoid duplicating the expression. Here's how you'd do that;

```
WITH CTE AS 
( 
    SELECT * FROM ... 
),
CteWithLoss AS ( 
    SELECT *, [dbo].[udf_BetaInv](A, B, C, D) AS 'Loss' 
    FROM CTE
)
SELECT *
FROM CteWithLoss 
WHERE (Loss >= @MinRetention);
```

On a side note: See if you can break the habit of starting your CTE definitions with `;WITH` and instead get into the habit of ending all your SQL statements with a semi-colon. It's more readable and better practice.

Comment: I need the second CTE inside the first one, the query depends on it. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Plus one for "break the habit of starting your CTE definitions with ;WITH"

Answer (score 0):

Below is the example of nested `CTE`.

```
with cte_data as 
(
    Select * from [HumanResources].[Department]
),cte_data1 as
(
    Select * from cte_data
)

select * from cte_data1
```

Comment: That's not nested, just another CTE referencing an earlier one.

Comment: This is nested Dave. In fact it's pretty much the definition of a nested CTE. Were you thinking of recursive CTE's? That's a whole new ball game and a lot more fun but not what the OP requested.